# Splitting the electricity bill

Tags: combinatorics

This is a similar question, but not quite - [click](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63874/is-there-a-simple-math-behind-splitting-multiple-bills-evenly-across-many-people)

Problem:

3 people stay at a flat and they need to divide the electricity bill fairly. They took one meter reading when they moved in and 1 meter reading $k$ weeks later. For those $k$ weeks, person $A$ has been in the flat for $x$ weeks, person $B$ has been there for $y$ weeks, and person $C$ has been there for $z$ weeks, $0\leq x,y,z 
\leq k$.

Assumptions:

Every person used the same amount when they were in the flat. Also the people stay an integer amount of weeks.

Question:

How to divide the bill in a fair way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Person A should pay the fraction $x/(x+y+z)$ of the bill, and similarly for persons B,C with $y,z$ replacing the numerator $x$ of person A's fraction. It has nothing to do with $k$ because presumably they have to split the bill no matter how many weeks they were there.

(This means e.g. if $(x,y,z)=(1,2,3)$ the proportions are $1/6,2/6,3/6$ respectively, even if they were there 6 weeks, or 7 weeks, or any integer number of weeks more. If the largest of $x,y,z$ is less than $k$ I guess the flat was empty during that time, but fees would still accumulate as they usually do, and at the end they would still have to split the total fairly.)

Answer (score 0):

NOTICE: This is for dividing the bill just in case they stayed alone each time! (Don't undestood the question well, sorry...)

For easy understanding:

Sum up all days (or weeks), those days are the 100% of the bill, then extract the percentage of each one depending on the days he stayed:

One person will pay ((Days stayed)/(total days))*(total bill).

For example if you have a bill of $100 that covers 30 days and one person stayed 10 days, that person will pay:

(10/30)*100 = $33.33 (one third).

Comment: Your answer contradicts @coffeemath , I think

Comment: If a bill of \$100 covers 30 days and everyone stayed all 30 days, what will you do with the extra \$200 left over?

Comment: Oh wait... I thought that they stayed alone each time!! Yeah, there are times that they stayed together... So that is a bit more complicated.

Comment: By the way @coffeemath answered while I was answering and has a perfect answer so I'm not going to edit mine, just clarify it.